# Laptop plugged in not charging, Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, battery, dell-inspiron, laptop-repair

At least **once every week**, laptop shows this problem of plugged in and not charging.
It starts working again only after reinstalling drivers (Microsoft acpi control battery driver) and removing battery for a while and re-insert again.

I have Windows 7 ultimate 64 bit.
Can anybody help, I am frustrated by having to remove battery every week from laptop.

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 3521 by the way.

Comment: What do the Application and System event logs show when it has its issue? (windows key + r > eventvwr.msc > Windows Logs)

Comment: What about installing Dell BIOS and Power driver updates?

Comment: @John system is updated.

Comment: @Meow_ly  (Eap method DLL path name) this was there..
Meow_ly - \Device\NDMP7 Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller  and this too

Comment: Try once resetting the battery by using it down to 5% or 10% and then charge it all the way up to 100%.  See if resetting the battery helps.

Comment: How old is the battery?

Comment: @Moab 2 years only

Answer (score -1):

By default Dells won't charge when battery is over 90% to conserve charge cycles. This threshold can be changed though, either in BIOS or using Dell Power Manager program.

Comment: Downvoter, please explain what's wrong with this answer and how it could be improved. Downvoting without explanation isn't helpful.